# Sqlalchemy postgresql null and None convertion in JSONB typefield

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, jsonb

I save 3 level dictionaries in postgresql with sqlalchemy as jsonb type:

```
{'result': {'key_0': {...}, 'key_1': {...}, None: {...}}
```

After querying row I have got None converted to string

```
{'result': {'key_0': {...}, 'key_1': {...}, u'null': {...}}
```

Is this sqlalchemy bug?

postgresql 9.4, sqlalchemy 1.0.8, ubuntu server 12.04.5

Answer (score 2):

It looks about right to me.

In javascript (and hence json) I believe that dictionary indices get converted to strings. So - it generates something like:

```
myvar[null] = {...}
```

which becomes

```
myvar['null'] = {...}
```

In any case, seeing null used as a dictionary key would make me run for the hills. I would recommend against it.

Comment: standart json python lib correctly dumps and loads data from json string. null from json string correctly converts to None.